# Why are the watch values formatted strangely (text/html/xml visualizers will not appear) in VS 2010 for my XBOX 360 ADK Reference Application Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xbox360, xbox

While attempting to use the Visual Studio 2010 debugger on an Xbox 360 ADK Reference application, I'm noticing that the watch values in the debug output are formatted strangely.

Once I earn enough reputation points (new user) I will post a screenshot.

The 'value' field should be a string however it starts with '0x004df938'. Because of this none of the visualizers are available to me.

NOTE: I do not have 'Hexadecimal display' enabled.

I have done a lot of searching and have only found one other issue close to what I am experiencing:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/ac20a4d8-8519-4daa-a8b4-efe88d9fda24

(the screenshot contained in the above link mirrors what I am seeing on my end)

The person who posed the problem changed their target platform (in the project configuration manager) from Any CPU to x86 but I was unable to do this (there is no x86 option available in the following UI):

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The following is what the output looks like: result 0x002e1480 {Length=1214 Value=0x002e1488 "<categories><category>Action &amp; Adventure</category><category>Anime &amp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mismatch between the ADK and XDK versions installed on the machine. The system had the July release of the XDK and the April release of the ADK. Once I uninstalled the April version and installed the July version (July 2012 QFE ADK) my problems were resolved.